# why animation does not work in my function?

Tags: c#, wpf

view.xaml code:

```xml
<UserControl>
<UserControl.Resources>
       <Style x:Key="CraneDataItemsControlTemplate" TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <co:CraneButtonCtl CraneNo="{Binding No}" 
                                           CraneName ="{Binding Name}" 
                                           CraneStatus="{Binding Status}"
                                           SmallCarYLocation="{Binding SmallCarY}"
                                           Width="{Binding Width}"
                                           Height="{Binding Height}"
                                           ShadowBackground="{Binding ShadowBkBrush}"
                                           RailBackground="{Binding SmallCarRailBrush}"
                                           SmallCarBackground="{Binding SmallCarBrush}"
                                           />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</<UserControl.Resources>
<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightBlue">
    <Canvas>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="craneData" ItemsSource="{Binding CraneDataList.Values}"
                              Style="{StaticResource CraneDataItemsControlTemplate}"/>
    </Canvas>
</Border>
          
</UserControl>
```

`CraneButtonCtl` is custom button.`CraneDataList` is viewmodel.
Then in view.xaml.cs, i create an animation when CraneData'X changed:

```cs
        public T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string propertyName, object propertyValue) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (parent == null) return null;

            T child = null;
            int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
            {
                DependencyObject visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                T element = visual as T;
                if (element == null)
                {
                    child = FindVisualChild<T>(visual, propertyName, propertyValue);
                    if (child != null)
                        break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (element.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) != null
                        && element.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(element).Equals(propertyValue))
                    {
                        child = (T)element;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        child = FindVisualChild<T>(visual, propertyName, propertyValue);
                        if (child != null)
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return child;
        }

//....

       private async Task BigCarMoveAnimation(string craneNo,int deltx)
        {
            var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

            //获取数据源
            var dataContext = DataContext as CraneCanvasViewModel;

            var from = dataContext.CraneDataList[craneNo].X;
            dataContext.CraneDataList[craneNo].MoveBigCar(deltx);
            var to = from + deltx;



            var animation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = from,
                To = to,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
                AccelerationRatio = 0.2,
                DecelerationRatio = 0.8,
                EasingFunction = new PowerEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut }
            };

       
            var btn = FindVisualChild<CraneButtonCtl>(craneData, "CraneNo", craneNo);
            //var btn = FindItem(craneData, "No", craneNo);
            if (btn != null)
            {
                Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, btn);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
                //animation.SetTarget(btn, Canvas.LeftProperty);

                var storyboard = new Storyboard();
                storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

                storyboard.Completed += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    tsc.TrySetResult(null);
                };

                storyboard.Begin();
            }

            await tsc.Task;
        }
```

Why the animation does not work when i call `BigCarMoveAnimation`, `btn` is not null.
I check btn's parent is null ,not canvas, is the reason?

Comment: Can you try to remove the `animation.SetTarget(btn, Canvas.LeftProperty);` line? It seems redundant since you already use `Storyboard.SetTarget`.

Comment: @Smartis it does not work yet..